# Can .spec.replicas count can be exceeded for a deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Just wanted to double check if there is a situation where the actual number of serving replicas can exceed the number defined in .spec.replicas for a deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your strategy, while the rollout is in progress, you can have more pods than number of replicas.

`.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge` controls how many extra pods may be spun up during the deployment.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#strategy

Once the rollout is complete, the desired and current number of replicas will match.